# Заменить один адрес в множестве файлов

Tags: dll, hex

Есть очень много файлов в которых есть бинарный код

Есть ли какой нибудь редактор который бы заходил и заменял в каждом из файле один адресс

Comment: попробуйте 010 Editor.